# UIBarButton does not go back to Menu

Tags: ios

This may be a simple answer, but I am new to this... my back button in the navigation bar is confused and does not want to go back to the Main Menu. Instead, it goes back to the previous view. How can I specify in my app that the "back" button should always go to to a specific view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is create a UIBarButton and connect an outlet to it. In the action:

```
  -(IBAction)MainMenu 
   {
       [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   }
```

Comment: I did exactly that... my UIBarButton is not responding. My .h file says "IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *MainMenu; and I connected an outlet to it...

Comment: @GeorgeFriday Connect an **ACTION** and call it MainMenu

Comment: Thanks, now it works! any ideas how to make a "pointed" button, like the "Back" button?

Comment: @GeorgeFriday You can find an image on google that has the pointed back button and add it to your bar button

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go back to the root controller:

> popToRootViewControllerAnimated:

Pops all the view controllers on the stack except the root view controller and updates the display.

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

If you want to go back to an specific controller:

> popToViewController:animated:

Pops view controllers until the specified view controller is at the top of the navigation stack.

Comment: I added your code in my viewdidappear section, but now it automatically goes back to the main menu when the view is selected...

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a new outlet in your view controller to handle the button press. Then use the code NSElvis posted in his answer to pop to root.

Comment: I connected the button by using IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *MainMenu; and then added NSElvis' code in my .m file -(IBAction)MainMenu {...} but nothing happens when I push the button... any ideas?